# Jest with Styled Components error: Syntax error parsing expected css: missing '}'

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, styled-components

I'm trying to use jest with styled components to test a component's styles, and I'm having the error:

```
Syntax error parsing expected css: missing '}' here
Failing css:
[object Object]
```

My component is a simple link with styled-components:

```
import styled from 'styled-components'

export const Link = styled.a`
  color: #fff;
`
```

My test:

```
describe('Link', () => {
  it('should display color on the link', () => {
    render(<Link href="/x">Test</Link>)
  }

  expect(screen.getByRole('link', { name: /test/i })).toHaveStyle({ color: '#fff' })
}
```

I'm running the npm react-scripts test.

I've tried to import 'jest-styled-components' and '@testing-library/jest-dom'

Answer (score 2):

It is probably because of the version of `@testing-library/jest-dom` package you are using.

For v4.2.4, [toHaveStyle(css: string)](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom/tree/v4.2.4#tohavestyle), as you can see, the matcher only support `string` parameter. Therefore, you should use

```js
expect(link).toHaveStyle(`color: #fff`);
```

It supports JS object parameter since [v5.1.0](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom/commit/7921e4a0a9e21e419122951eb28ed270c13209c5#diff-b335630551682c19a781afebcf4d07bf978fb1f8ac04c6bf87428ed5106870f5R644)